# Google Pie Chart on Android

Tags: android, pie-chart

I tried to use google pie chart in my android application and here is my code

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
static HomeFragment fragment;
private WebView webView;
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    String customHtml = "<html>"+"<head>"+"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"jsapi.js\">  </script>"
    +"<script type=\"text/javascript\">"
    +"google.load(\"visualization\", \"1\", {packages:[\"corechart\"]});"
    +"google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);"
    +"function drawChart() {"
    +"var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(["+"['Task', 'Hours per Day'],"+"['Work',    11],"+"['Eat',      2],"+"['Commute',  2],"+"['Watch TV', 2],"+"['Sleep',    7]"+"]);"
    +"var options = {"+"      title: 'My Daily Activities'"+"   };"
    +"  var chart = newgoogle.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));"
    +"  chart.draw(data, options);"+"}"+"</script>"+"</head>"+"<body>"
    +" <div id=\"piechart\" style=\"width: 900px; height: 500px;\"></div>"
    +"</body>"+"</html>";
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
    return rootView;
    }
```

}

//the layout

```
<WebView  
android:id="@+id/webView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

I added the internet permission But it ic not working and I am getting this error

```
E/NativeCrypto(24611): ssl=0x5bf95f38 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x5e6dfab0 arg=0x0
E/NativeCrypto(24611): ssl=0x5bf95f38 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
E/PerfService(528): perfBoostEnable bypassed!
E/PerfService(528): perfBoostDisable bypassed!
E/hwcomposer_v1.0(499): [WKR] Timed out waiting for FrameSyncThread...
E/PerfService(528): perfBoostEnable bypassed!
E/PerfService(528): perfBoostDisable bypassed!
E/PerfService(528): perfBoostEnable bypassed!
E/PerfService(528): perfBoostDisable bypassed!
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the chart drawn in the Android browser is by making the below 2 changes.

"  var chart = **newgoogle**.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));"

add space between **new** and **google** in the above line like,

"  var chart = **new google**.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));"

and

Replace **src=\"jsapi.js**   by   **src=\"https://www.google.com/jsapi\"**

Other way is to add "jsapi.js" in the assets folder and calling the method loadDataWithBaseURL() instead of loadData() as shown below.

**webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);**

If you have any problems in loading the chart, use the debug tools of any webbrowser (chrome, mozilla firefox, internet explorer). Then you can find the error easily.

Keep developing...